# Javascript displays more text boxes depending on a pull down option?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I don't know if this is possible in Javascript but I am trying to achieve this. I don't know the terminology so I thought I would post it on here with pseudo code to help you understand what I want to implement.

Pseudo Code:

- User Selects Option from pull down.
- If selection matches criteria
- Add text boxes to the form
- Else if selection is something else
- Add invisible text box with NULL value

I would like to code it myself but if you could post some reference material or links as I have not done much with Javascript.

Thanks

Comment: In plain JavaScript, or with a JS library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first and second entries, google for 'html select onchange'.

You'll want to check out [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createElement) for "Add text boxes to the form"

To make your text box invisible, check out the [CSS `display` property](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display), setting it to `none` or `block (or inline)`

I've tried to keep this answer very short without code samples because it sounds like you want to do it yourself.  Add a comment to my answer if you want more of an example.

**EDIT**

Also of note, along with document.createElement, you will want to look at [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) to add the created element to an HTML element, most likely some FORM element in your page.

Comment: Also, as an addenda, it's worth remembering that there is ***no*** html element called a 'textbox:' there's either `<input type="text" />` or `<textarea></textarea>`.

Comment: @David Agreed and good point to bring up.  I tend to use the term `textbox` as a high-level term that means either `input type=text` or `textarea`, based on the context of the conversation.

Comment: Thankyou, I now feel like I can begin this task more confidentally. :)